# replace smilies :) to images PHP

Tags: php

So maybe someone can help me get on the right track.

I have a guestbook thats works, now im trying to change the smilies :) to emoticons.

I can display emoticons that i have in a database, but when im entering a smile in the guestbook it wont change to the icon. I think it something with my while loops, but i can't get it, since I am a Rookie.

my textarea code

```
<form action='process.php' method='post'>

<p>Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' /> </p>
<p>Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' /> </p>
<p>Comment: </p>
    <p><textarea name='comment' rows="7" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    <hr />
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Post Entry' /></p>
        </form>
```

This is my php code.

```
    <?php
    $path = "images"; 

    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Error: Couldn't connect to database"); 
    $db = mysql_select_db("guestbook");

    $query = "SELECT emote, image FROM emoticons"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 


    /*EMO ovanför*/

   $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die ('FEL INDEX');
$db = mysql_select_db('guestbook');

    $query = mysql_query('select * from guestbook order by id desc');
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($num_rows > 0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
    $emotes[] = $row['emote']; 
    $images[] = "<img src='" . $path . "/" . $row['image'] . "'>"; 
    } 
    // Query the database, and assign the result-set to $result 

        //display entries
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo "
            <p>
            <b>Name: </b>".$row['name']."

            </p>

            <p>
            <b>Email: </b>".$row['email']."

            </p>

            <p>
            <b>Comment: </b>".$row['comment']."
            </p>

            <p>
            <b>Date: </b>".$row['date']." | Time: ".$row['time']."
            </p>
            <hr />
            ";

        }
    $text = ":) ;) :( :p "; 
    echo str_replace($emotes, $images, $text); 

        }



    ?>
```

As you se one of my last rows is getting the images from the database. that works like a charm but not when im writing smilies in the guestbook.

Comment: See if this helps http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/MySQL/Quick-and-Dirty-Emoticons/1/, as the title says `quick and dirty`

Comment: That helped to understand how to display the emoticons from a database, but not change the smilies in the guestbook to emoticons :)<
Sorry but I am a newbie :)

Comment: what dose your `textarea` input code look like and JS, please post it

Comment: I edited my question with my textarea input code.

Answer (score 1):

you have to replace the strings that should be smileys to images like this:

```
$row['comment'] =str_replace(':)','<img src="smile.jpg">', $row['comment']);
```

directly in your while.

The path to the images has to be correct obv.

You could just copy that for all smileys, but it would be nicer if you create an array in which your smileys are and then replace it in a new loop

Comment: But can i change this 
$row['comment'] =str_replace(':)','<img src="images/smile001.gif">', $row['comment']);

With this one  $images[] = "<img src='" . $path . "/" . $row['image'] . "'>"; 

So I can get the smilies from a database insted of usin an array ?

Comment: of course you can get them from a database.  but the first line does something differen than the second. Read the smilies from the database to an array (not in 2 as your actually doing, use one value as index) and then use foreach to loop through the array and replace the content

Answer (score 0):

you will not to be able to directly display the `emoticons images` in the `textarea` for example you would need to copy the input like SO dose and display the formatted output in a html element.

Comment: Thats really what Im trying to accomplished but I cant get how =/